# Conseguir que la función LOCATION me devuelva la carpeta donde está ubicado un documento web

Tags: javascript

¿hay forma de conseguir la carpeta donde esta ubicada una pagina?
Tengo un menu con las secciones POLITICA ECONOMIA SOCIAL, y quiero que cuando la gente entre a POLITICA la pestaña de esa sección se ponga roja. Hasta ahora he podido conseguir la ruta exacta con el siguiente codigo:

```
var L = window.location ;
```

if ( L == "politica.html" ) {
//estilo a aplicar
}

Pero necesito que el estilo se le aplique a todos los elementos que esten dentro de una carpeta llamada POLITICA, no solo a uno, y no voy a hacerlo uno por uno. Por eso quiero saber si la funcion LOCATION me puede retornar la carpeta donde se encuentra un elemento.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location` trae un objeto con varias propiedades, entre ellas `pathname`, siendo el caso que necesites que algo se le aplique a aquellos que tengan dentro de su ruta "politica".

> Aquí te hablo de rutas y no de carpetas, puesto que usando JS en el navegador no puedes saber cómo está estructurada la información en el servidor.

Un ejemplo sería

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
if(path.includes('/politica')) {
   /* lo que necesites hacer
      esto aplica para
      /politica.html
      /politica/uno.html
      /politica/dos.php
   y demás rutas */
}
```

Espero te sirva :)

Comment: El código también matchea rutas como `/politica.html`, `/noespolitica/politica/noespolitica.html`, y un sin fin más.

Comment: Exacto, así que probablemente lo mejor sería utilizar un regex como `/^\/politica(\/|\.html$)/.test(path)`